# Invaild URL: Invaild port specified

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to run the project using IIS Express and i get this error message
Invaild URL: Invaild port specified

I tryed to change the port but it does not work

Comment: Could you please share your `launchSettings.json` details?

Answer (score 0):

Please,send your `Properties/launchSettings.json`. Probably you must add `https://` to your url.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it seems you used the invalid port url inside your launchsetting.json file.

I suggest you could firstly check its IIS express settings to make sure it looks like below:

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:45519",
      "sslPort": 44315
    }
  }
```

Besides, the IIS express's SSL port range contains specific limit, the range must inside the 44300 through 44399 for SSL.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-without-administrative-privileges#using-ssl) to understand how it works .